# Closure Compiler @extends doesn't work when using "Class" container objects

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm in the process of annotating all my javascript for closure compiler, however -- the code I have currently heavily depends on defining classes within objects i.e:

```
Class.SomeClass = function() {};
Class.SomeOtherClass = function() {};
```

**rather than:**

```
function SomeClass() {};
SomeClass.prototype = {};
```

However, it gives me an warning when trying to annotate an extends ... the compiler is stating that i can't determine what type Class.SomeClass is:

```
JSC_TYPE_PARSE_ERROR: Bad type annotation. Unknown type Class.SomeObject 
*  @extends Class.SomeObject
```

Paste the following code below [into closure compiler with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home):

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

(function($) {

    "use strict";

    var Class = {};

    /**
     *  @constructor
     */
    Class.ObjectA = function() {};
    Class.ObjectA.prototype = {};

    /**
     *  @constructor
     *  @extends Class.ObjectA
     */
    Class.ObjectB = function() {};
    Class.ObjectB.prototype = $.extend(new Class.ObjectA(), {
        initialize: function() {}
    });


    window.test = new Class.ObjectB();
    window.test.initialize();

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer isn't obvious. You simply need to add an `@const` to your `Class` namespace.

```
/** @const */
var Class = {};
```

Comment: This is definitely correct, though it's been making me run into other issues specifically surrounding custom methods to automatically extend a prototype (such as $.extend).  How are you dealing with inheritance this way?

Comment: Custom methods that extend an object hide the extension from the compiler. There is no easy way around that. You'll either need to avoid doing that, or provide stub definitions that are then overwritten by $.extend. jQuery provides some big challenges for the developer wanting to use the full power of Closure-Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

well the easiest, since you will be compiling it in advance mode anyway is to maybe use goo.provide and just link the base.js in. then obviously you should use goog.inherits for your inheritance since advanced mode understand the base.js functions a lot better than say $.extends.

so my code to achieve the same would look like this:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @use_closure_library true
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

goog.provide('Class.ObjectA')

/**
*  @constructor
*/
Class.ObjectA = function() {};

goog.provide('Class.ObjectB');
/**
*  @constructor
*  @extends Class.ObjectA
*/
Class.ObjectB = function() {};
Class.ObjectB.prototype =
{
    initialize: function() {}
}

goog.inherits(Class.ObjectB, Class.ObjectA);


window.test = new Class.ObjectB();
window.test.initialize();
```

In the compiler ui, you have to select the option to add the closure library which will add goog.base.

Now  you also have several jqueury style foo's in your approach like (function($) {})(jQuery); which i would reassess the use of if you are starting down the advanced compilation route (i would personally reasses the use of jquery versus the closure library, but I do know of people who continued using jquery with advanced). going down the advanced mode I would also recomend that you look at a build system like plovr.

Comment: This solution requires you to use at least part of closure-library. For many people, that's not ideal.

Comment: I saw your @const. yeah, i realise not using goog.base is prefered for some people (from your postings to the list and here I know you use jquery and not goog.dom) but since he is using advanced mode and dead code gets eliminated I reckon using the operators which the compiler natively understands is better.

Comment: I appreciate this, however -- using the goog.dom methods and such isn't really viable for me.  I wish there were a middle ground between advanced and simple optimizations -- .  I may go this route in the future, but as of right now jQuery is a requirement ....